# gradle 2.8-2.10 performance

Tags: gradle

I am running same gradle task: **gradle clean web:test** with different 3 gradle versions.

gradle 2.10: 2 min 37 seconds. 2 failing tests.
gradle 2.9: 2 min 59 seconds. 2 failing tests.
gradle 2.8: 1 min 42 seconds. all tests are ok.

Are there some new configuration parameters in 2.9-2.10 versions?
Any ideas why there such a poor performance in 2.9-2.10 versions compared to 2.8?

Comment: Gradle point releases are intended to be totally backwards compatible. It'd be better if you mentioned some details about the plugins you're using, or how your tests are failing.

Comment: It's a multi-module project where web is one of the modules. Tests: Spring MockMvc tests. 2 of them are failing in gradle 2.9 and 2.10. My main concern why it is ok in gradle 2.8 and much faster.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Eric.  Gradle is really focusing on speed/configuration time in their last several releases, since 2.4.  So, I'm skeptical that these builds can be properly compared, e.g. it may have to do with plugin versions changing behavior.  You should use the `--profile` option on each to see where the time is spent.